# Can't access the values stored in model in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm using `models` to call the stored values entered by user in form (in view page)

Now working in controllers to access the stored values from model.

`VerifyProof(string proofRecordId)` methods calls for another method `VerifyFirstName(proof)` which does the actual verification.

the problem is that I can access the values from model in `VerifyProof()` method but can't access the values stored in model in
`VerifyFirstName()` method.

I commented the important parts, have a look

```
public async Task<IActionResult> VerifyProof(string proofRecordId, ConnectionDetailsViewModel model) // ConnectionDetailsViewModel is the name of model
{
    var modelFirstName = model.HolderFirstName; // the value is stored in model.HolderFirstName
        
    var agentContext = await _agentProvider.GetContextAsync();
    var proofRecord = await _proofService.GetAsync(agentContext, proofRecordId);
    var request = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ProofRequest>(proofRecord.RequestJson);
    var proof = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PartialProof>(proofRecord.ProofJson);
    bool verified = false;
    switch (request.Name)
    {
        case "ProveYourFirstName":
            verified = VerifyFirstName(proof, model); break; // to call the VerifyFirstName Method (where verification happens)
        default:
            break;
    }
    if (!verified)
    {
        proofRecord.State = ProofState.Rejected;
        await _walletRecordService.UpdateAsync(agentContext.Wallet, proofRecord);
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}

public bool VerifyFirstName(PartialProof proof, ConnectionDetailsViewModel model)
{
    var name = proof.RequestedProof.RevealedAttributes.First();
    if (name.Value.Raw.Equals(holderfirstName)) // instead of holderfirstName, I want to call the model.HolderFirstName
    { 
        return true; 
    }

    return false;
}
```

Values stored in variables in `VerifyProof()` method

```
var agentContext = Hyperledger.Aries.Agents.DefaultAgentContext

var proofRecord = ProofRecord: State=Accepted, ConnectionId=9e066590-ee03-47e9-8ed2-65e860b8bb10, RequestJson=[hidden], ProofJson=[hidden], ProofRecord: Id=5903845b-ac9e-4a46-b249-a7badc5f8820, TypeName=AF.ProofRecord, CreatedAtUtc=7/21/2020 8:18:26 AM, UpdatedAtUtc=7/21/2020 8:18:38 AM

var request = ProofRequest: Name=ProveYourFirstName, Version=1.0, Nonce=1189684984146391381555794, RequestedAttributes=[ProveYourFirstName, Hyperledger.Aries.Features.PresentProof.ProofAttributeInfo], RequestedPredicates=, NonRevoked=

var proof = Hyperledger.Aries.Features.PresentProof.PartialProof
```

**ProofsViewModel.cs**

```
public class ProofsViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<ProofRecord> Proofs { get; set; }

}

public class ProofsDetailViewModel
{
    public ProofRecord ProofRecord { get; set; }
    public ProofRequest ProofRequest { get; set; }
    public PartialProof PartialProof { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You have to pass the declare and pass the parameter along

Comment: I already did that, but it returns an error..

Comment: in `VerifyProof()` method I already did that.. and it's working.. but in `VerifyFirstName()`, it return an error... can u please provide a code snippet.. how will achieve that.. :)

Comment: `public bool VerifyFirstName(PartialProof proof, ConnectionDetailsViewModel model) {...}`. Call it from `VerifyProof` as `VerifyFirstName(proof, model)`

Comment: it didn't return an error, but can't access the value stored in model.. wrote this code in `VerifyFirstName(proof, model) ` method .. `if (name.Value.Raw.Equals(model.HolderFirstName))` and it returns nothing..

Comment: Please be more specific. What does "can't access" mean? What returns nothing?

Comment: there is value stored in `model.HolderFirstName`, I want access/fetch this in `VerifyFirstName()` method.. but can't.. and able to access/fetch in `VerifyProof()` method

Comment: That seems unlikely. Set a breakpoint in `VerifyFirstName` and confirm that.

Comment: check value of "request.Name"... doesn't seem like this would work when sending json.

Comment: basically the `(name.Value.Raw.Equals())` is where I'm checking is this value (stored in `model.HolderFirstName`) equal to `name.Value.Raw`

Comment: in the switch: switch (request.Name)

Comment: Could you share your `PartialProof ` model and what is the `RequestedProof `and `RevealedAttributes`.

Comment: @pcalkins, the value of `request.Name` is `ProveYourFirstName`

Comment: I added the section above of all the Values stored in variables in `VerifyProof()` method.. have a look

Comment: @Renam, above I add the code of `ProofsViewModel.cs` page (`PartialProof` model)

Comment: seems like a lot of this should use class-wide variables... so the methods can access them in their scope.  You may also have some weirdness happening with async/non-async calls mixed.  Try to make it async all the way through... so that VerifyFirstName is also async.